# PHP count array keys in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have a simple array like so :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Colors] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [value] => Blue
                )

        )

    [Sizes] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [value] => 10
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [value] => 30

                )

        )

)
```

then I just want to count array keys [Colors] and [Sizes], which should give me 2 in total, but using count() like count($array), throws `"Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"`

Comment: yours is not an array, its an object

Comment: Ok, is there a way to perform count, it's json object.

Comment: could you `var_dump()` please?

Comment: What would the array look like with more than one color?

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42814

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an object with two properties (`Colors` and `Sizes`) (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php).

Use `get_object_vars` (https://php.net/get_object_vars) to get the properties of your object, then count it:

```
$number_of_properties = count(get_object_vars($your_std_class_object));
```

Comment: PHP's `get_object_vars` is for an object, the question was for an array.

Comment: @John the code in the question is about object. The answers and comments (not only mine) mention this point. The answer is accepted, it means it works also for Aiko . Why downvote?

Comment: I stand corrected, they used an object instead of an array and you answered the object question. The OP needs to learn the difference between objects and arrays then. Edited to negate down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variable is `$obj`

```
count(get_object_vars($obj));
// return 2, for your object variables are two: Colors & Sizes (both arrays)


count($obj->Colors);
// return 1, for your object variable (Colors) (which is array) has only one element


count($obj->Sizes);
// return 2, for your object variable (Sizes) (which is array) has two elements


count(get_object_vars($obj->Sizes[0]));
// return 1, for your object variable(Size)'s [0] index has only 1 object element, i.e. 10
```